# Excel- Preventing cell references from changing when the data in those references is moved around

Tags: excel

I have a range of cells that references another range of cells on another sheet. For our purposes today let's say $C1:$C10 references $A1:$A10. Now theoretically whatever gets put in A1 should go to C1 and whatever goes in A2 goes to C2. This part works fine.

Where I'm running into an issue is if I want to reorder the list in A1:A10. If cut and insert A10 into A1 everything shifts down and all the data is still between A1:A10 but nothing in C1:C10 has changed except now C10 references A1. I have changed reference types($A$1, $A1 and A$1) but no luck.

I essentially want the freedom to move around or replace data within A1:A10 and have C1:C10 automatically update.

Comment: You could use `INDEX` perhaps, like `=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,ROW())`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Excel does this by design.

When you move a cell, you are not just moving the contents of that cell, you are moving the entire container - value, formatting, data validation, **references**, and all.

This is very helpful when that is what you need. Less helpful when it isn't.

To work around this, you will need to remove the direct reference to that cell.

You can do this in a number of ways.

For example, you could use `INDIRECT`, however, I would recommend against this as it is a volatile formula and will recalculate every time a cell is changed. If you have a lot of these, it can quickly slow down your workbook.

@BigBen's suggestion of using INDEX, is probably the best:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$10,ROW())
```

Be aware that the reference to $A$1:$A$10 will still be updated if you move the entire range at once.